# Simple and short conditional probablity calculation

Tags: probability

PLEASE refer here, for a better, more clear, rephrasing of the below: [Conditional probability related genetics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922534/conditional-probability-related-genetics)

This is a followup from a bigger question, however this specific question is solely involved with calculations, so I'd say it belongs here. I am **pretty** sure the following is sufficient to solve this, but not **entirely** sure!

The chances of a specific couple of having a child who will suffer from cystic fibrosis (CF) is $1.58$% which is approximately $\frac1{63}$. What is their chance of having a child who will suffer from CF, given that they already have 2 healthy children? **(Conditional probability & Bayes's formula calculation)**
The two events are independent.

CF is a hereditary disease, autosomally recessive
The mother is a carrier
The chance of a randomally selected person in the entire population to be sick is $0.25$%.
The chances of the father to be a carrier are $\frac{2}{21}$.
The father is healthy.

The answer should be approximately $0.9$%

What I did was using the conditional probability formula, but obviously I'm doing something wrong: $P(A/B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{ P(B)}$, where $A$ is the event of having a sick child, with probability of = $\frac1{63}$, and $B$ is the event of having 2 healthy children, with probability of = $(\frac{62}{63})^{2}$, and these 2 events are independent. Then, the calculation becomes $\frac{P(A)\cdot P(B)}{P(B)}=P(A)=\frac1{63}$ which is wrong.. My logic is wrong obviously but I do not know where.

Comment: Please include your attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: The problem is not well phrased.  Are we to suppose that, between siblings, the occurrence of CF is independent?  That is, at least, not at obvious assumption.  And what does the $1.58\%$ figure mean?  Is it the probability that a randomly selected child has the disease or is it, as you said, the probability that a specific couple will have at least one child that has it?  And are we asking about the next child born or about all the subsequent children (in which case we need statistics about the number of children).

Comment: @Lovsovs, attempt included

Comment: @lulu, the events are independent. The $1.58$% figure means that when this couple has a child, the chances of him to be born sick are $1.58$%. Now, they have 2 healthy children, and we are asked, given that, what is the chance of the next child to be born sick. And just the next ONE.

Comment: If the events are independent then the next one has probability $1.58\%$.  That's what independent means.

Comment: You've left out a lot of information.  CF is hereditary.  Are we to assume that both parents are carriers?  If not, then the fact that they have had two healthy kids provides some evidence that they aren't both carriers.  If, on the other hand, we do assume they are both carriers then you are correct that the events are independent...but then the probability for each child is a constant.  (it isn't what you said , however.  Looking online the probability is at least $25\%$, increasing if one parent actually expresses the disease).

Comment: @lulu, you are correct. I'm sorry, and I'll now update it with more information.

Comment: @lulu Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45232/discussion-between-matan-and-lulu).

Comment: Great, I retracted my vote to close!

Comment: @Lovsovs Thanks! Are you now able to solve this?

Comment: I don't like to go into chat rooms, sorry.  My suggestion:  reprint the question in its entirety, exactly as it appears.  Include the larger question you allude to.  My guess is that you mean NOT to assume that both parents are carriers...so that each healthy birth provides evidence that at least one parent isn't a carrier.  But if I am right, you need to provide more information in order to do the calculation.

Comment: @lulu , I've reposted the question. Here it is: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922534/conditional-probability-related-genetics

Comment: @Lovsovs, I've reposted the question. Here it is: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922534/conditional-probability-related-genetics

Comment: All right, then please delete this one.